# Question regarding WP multisite feature

Tags: theme-development, multisite, user-roles

Hi I am developing a networking website using wp multisite feature. The website will have three different sites.

1. buystuff.abc.com
2. sellstuff.abc.com
3. rentstuff.abc.com

Now if "X" person register on buystuff.abc.com and complete his profile. Will he be able to access the other two sites with same credentials used on to register on buystuff.abc.com?

Answer (score 0):

First [read this](http://codex.wordpress.org/Roles_and_Capabilities).

THen you can [try this](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/multisite-user-management/)

Answer (score 0):

By default user are global across the network as Subscriber (more or less). They can only visit the admin area of the main blog and edit only their profile and blogs they're assigned to.

If you want to give all users access to all sites, you have to assign them to these sites manually or use [Multisite User Management](http://wordpress.org/plugins/multisite-user-management/) plugin which will do it automatically for you.

Comment: Thanks! for your responses guys. I liked multisite user management plugin to automate user management.